# Semantically, what is a forum?

Tags: html, semantics, forum

I'm building a forum from scratch as a project, and I'm trying to make it as well-formed and standards-based as possible. Thus far, I've come up with

- Using a table
- Using an unordered list with headings for the relevant data
- Using a table for post data (author, title, date, post number) inside a list of posts, with a sub-list of threads

Are there other options I should consider? If not, which of the above would be most semantically correct

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to go for the more traditional forum look, then semantically the list of threads should be displayed as a table because it is tabular data (has rows, columns, and headers). The posts of the thread itself should probably be displayed as an ordered list because posts are ordered by date.

Answer (score 1):

Some more features of common forums:

- # times viewed
- Last posted author/thread where applicable
- stickied (stays at the top, always)
- "poll" threads
- announcement threads (appear on all forums always at the top)
- subforums
- "upvoting" thread replies as "helpful" (aka kudos system)